# How to stop edits on linked tables from changing the actual table data MS Access 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I am not sure what the correct forum is for a question like this, so if it would go better on a different one could you move it there please?

I have split my database into a front and back-end database. The front end is using linked tables which are linked to the back-end real tables. If a user changes something in a table on the front-end database, the changes are carried over to the backend database.

Why is this and how can I prevent this from happening? Is there a way to change the settings to make the database read only? Whether it's through VBA or not, I would accept either answer.

Comment: How about if you open the form using the acFormReadOnly switch?

Comment: Are the users directly editing the tables, or are they accessing the data through a form. If you're using a form, you can create an _unlinked_ form and handle pushing the data back when the user clicks `Save`, or through it out if they hit `Cancel`. If they're directly editing the table, see [Mat's Mug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37865841/2344413)'s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a feature, not a bug. You're using a linked table, it's *linked*.

If you want a separate table, make a separate table, and make some ETL (extract/transform/load) process to keep the two tables in sync as needed, accordingly with whatever business rules you need to implement.

If your Access DB is connecting to SQL Server via SQL authentication, you could have the SQL user on the SQL Server side only authorized to `SELECT`, and denied `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` permissions. Expect errors on the Access side when the linked table is modified then.